# No result defined for action and result input for validation

Tags: jsp, jquery, struts2

This is my struts.xml

```
<struts>
  <include file="example.xml"/>

  <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />

  <package name="register" namespace="/register" extends="struts-default,json-default">
    <action name="Registration"  class="example.Registration">
      <result name="success">/SucessPage.jsp</result>
      <result name="input">/UserData.jsp</result>
    </action>

    <action name="validateEmailValue" method="validateEmailValue" 
            class="example.Registration">
      <result type="json"/>
    </action>
  </package>
</struts>
```

in jsp page

```
<s:form action="http://localhost:8080/MyRegistrationProject/register/Registration" 
        name="data" validate="true">
```

it validate  data but in my action class there are do method execute and `validateEmailValue`

I have make ajax call using getjson

```
$.getJSON("http://localhost:8080/MyRegistrationProject/register/validateEmailValue",
    { email:emailId },
    function(data) { alert("success") }
);
```

When I make call for validateEmailValue it gives following error

```
No result defined for action example.Registration and result input
```

Any Insight? Thanks

Comment: Can you show the code of example.Registration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you implemented `validate()` in your action class `example.Registration` right?

Even though you specified to call the method `validateEmailValue()` on your action `validateEmailValue`, it will first run `validate()` and check if the validation succeed, and will forward the page to `INPUT` result if validation failed.

Since your `validateEmailValue` action do not have a `INPUT` result declared, system throw the error you saw.

Try adding the `INPUT` result to your  `validateEmailValue` action and see what is shown.

```
<result name="input" type="json"/>
```